# How can I get a mobile number on Android Real device? I am using Android phonegap concept

Tags: android, cordova, telephonymanager

I want to display my phone number on the Android phone. I am using the following code for displaying the number on the phone, but I am getting a null value on the phone. Here is my code:

```
TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager) mGap.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imeiId=tm.getLine1Number();
```

I displayed `imeiId` on Device but it is displaying null. Is there any alternative for this problem?

I have added the below code in android manifest `.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

But it's showing null on the device. I am new to Android PhoneGap applications, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added the READ_PHONE_STATE permission in the manifest?

Answer (score 3):

Try this actually

```
private String getMyPhoneNumber(){
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
    mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)
            getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
    return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
    }

    private String getMy10DigitPhoneNumber(){
            String s = getMyPhoneNumber();
            return s.substring(2);
    }
```

Taken from

http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-my-phone-number

Comment: Oh just realized, you are using PhoneGap. At present there is no built in command in PhoneGap which will get the devices number

Comment: write a plugin which returns u the phone number via the above code